# Extending Yii framework CHtml helper class with our custom class

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, yii, encode

I have to encode user entered data into utf-8, especially if it is numeric encode,
So I decided to use the following code snippet for encoding and then store it into database

```
$convmap = array ( 0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff );
$str = htmlentities ( mb_encode_numericentity( $str, $convmap, 'UTF-8' ),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8",false );
```

But Yii default encode uses only CHtml::encode() which uses only htmlspecialchars() function

So I have decided to extend CHtml class for overriding the encode function, but I can't figure out how to do it in Yii..
Suggest a good way to extend the Yii helper classes...

Comment: CHtml is static class with all static methods, You can not extend it. better use as a blackbox(composite), But still yii uses `CHtml`, not your

Comment: I want Kohana like extend feature for core helpers in Yii, bec. CHtml is tightly coupled with Yii core for encoding while saving data to db, or querying from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do it fully, This class is tightly integrated in the framework. ( i.e. used in widgets, activaeform's etc... ),

one thing you can do is ... extend it and create your class and use it in your entire application. Preprocess your model data before sending it to views/widgets.

Answer (score 1):

you could always edit the CHtml class itself in `/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php`, adding an extra param to the encode method? for example;

```
public static function encode($text,$extraEncode=false)
{
    if($extraEncode===true)
    {
        $convmap = array ( 0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff );
        return htmlentities ( mb_encode_numericentity( $text, $convmap, 'UTF-8' ),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8",false );
    } else {
        return htmlspecialchars($text,ENT_QUOTES,Yii::app()->charset);
    }
}
```

obv, edit to taste.

Then you can call it like `CHtml::encode($myString,true)`

Comment: It seems to edit Yii core system, but I don't want to edit Yii core, Give a solution without touching the Yii core system. I got a hint from this

Comment: You can't extend a class to include an encode function to override the CHtml method in the same way you can override a lot of the controller/model methods (e.g. `$this->beforeSave()`), the CHTML encode function is called statically a lot, which means you'd have to make edits the core files, I don't see the issue with this if it's done so it doesn't effect the original useage of the method, but if you were against this way, you could always create your own encode method totally separate and call your method (`MyClass::encode($myText)` instead of the CHtml method (`CHtml::encode($myText)`)?

Comment: Just found this, which is one way around... for now, hopefully they'll extend yii in future for a better solution: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11109-how-to-attach-behaviors-to-yii-built-in-helpers-eg-chtml/